# survival curves produced by survfit function in package survival

Tags: r, survival-analysis, survival

I am using the `survfit` function in the R package `survival` to create survival curves from a `survfit.coxph` object output by `coxph`. I have two methods for creating the curve which give different results. I believe the first is the correct answer, but I can't tell why method 2 does not work.

```
library(survival)
set.seed(1234)

## generate small data set
n <- 10
z <- rnorm(n,mean=0.4)
x <- rexp(n,exp(z))
y <- pmin(1,x)
del <- 1*(x < 1)
dat <- data.frame(y,del,z)

## fit cox model
fit <- coxph(Surv(y,del)~z,ties="breslow",data=dat)

## method 1
newdata <- dat[1,]
newdata[1,3] <- 0
out <- survfit(fit,newdata=newdata)
out$surv
##[1] 0.9557533 0.9048870 0.8545721 0.7599743 0.6397022 0.4218647 0.4218647


## method 2, why not same as method 1?
dat[1,3] <- 0
out <- survfit(fit,newdata=dat[1,])
out$surv
##[1] 0.9570757 0.9079589 0.8593546 0.7710287 0.6610956 0.4787354 0.4787354
```

Comment: That is a puzzle. (I get the same with R 3.5.2 and survival_2.43-3). I get TRUE for `identical(newdata, dat[1,])` and adding drop=FALSE as a third argument to "[" did not affect the results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In both methods `survfit` function receives two parameters: `fit` and `newdata`.

In the method 1 line `newdata[1,3] <- 0` changes only the object `newdata` and the object `dat` and consequently object `fit` are not changed.

In the method 2, instead, `dat[1,3] <- 0`  changes both, the object `newdata` and the object `fit`.

So the `newdata` objects received by `survfit` function are identical in both methods, as 42 correctly pointed out, but the `fit` objects are not.
If you make 3 identical dataframes in the beginning, you can see this.

```
dat1 <- data.frame(y,del,z)
dat2 <- data.frame(y,del,z)
dat3 <- data.frame(y,del,z)

## fit cox model
fit <- coxph(Surv(y,del)~z,ties="breslow",data=dat1)

## method 1
newdata <- dat2[1,]
newdata[1,3] <- 0

out <- survfit(fit,newdata=newdata)
out$surv
##[1] 0.9557533 0.9048870 0.8545721 0.7599743 0.6397022 0.4218647 0.4218647


## method 2, same as method 1
dat3[1,3] <- 0
out <- survfit(fit,newdata=dat3[1,])
out$surv
##[1] 0.9557533 0.9048870 0.8545721 0.7599743 0.6397022 0.4218647 0.4218647
```

Comment: Wow. I really amazed at that. I suspect it's not really supposed to be that way. Violates the usual functional paradigm to my way of thinking.

Comment: Thanks. I am wondering if this is a bug or me not using the function correctly.

Comment: Well, this, inheritance, mutating, lazy evaluation etc - it just behaves in certain ways.  -  sometimes you can use it, sometimes it can cause troubles if one is not aware..

Comment: ...and I don´t think that this is in any way specific for survfit function - I think you´ll come across it elsewhere as well..

Comment: And please, let me know if answer was not clear/detailed enough or if there are any follow-up questions..

Comment: @Oka But apparently your hint was not specific enough. That's my upvote.